# Hash text in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, hash, google-chrome-extension

I need to hash some values in chrome extension(sha256 and ripemd160 with key).

I can't use PHP to do it, JS doesn't have build in function to do it. Only solution I see is to send a request to server and recieve hash or insert liblary with hash function to my project, which is maybe possible.

What's the best way to hash values in Chrome Extensions and how to do it?

Comment: Did you try Googling Javascript Hash?  There are a bunch of libraries that will do that.

Comment: [Google's CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) library is one of them. Although, depending on how secure you want your hashes to be, you might not want your hashing code to be exposed in the browser (JS), and do it server-side instead.

Comment: Use the standard [Cryptography API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt).

Comment: Okay, I'll try to use this apis/liblaries Just I thougth I can't find simplier solution. After I'll success I'll post which thing solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) is simple liblary that let us hash text in JS. You just need to download correct algorythm .js file.

Then you simply link it to your project and use like that:

```
part1 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(textToHash, key);
part2 = CryptoJS.HmacRIPEMD160(textToHash, key);
```